# My navlink is not working in react.js but after reloading it works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, navbar, react-bootstrap

Developing a react.js app. Used nav link at navbar. The router is also defined but it doesn't go anywhere. after reloading it works. If Job Post is clicked on Navbar it doesn't work but in the URL it's `http://localhost:3000/jobPost` and after reloading it is routed.
App package.json is

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.34.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
```

```
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import Offcanvas from 'react-bootstrap/Offcanvas';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
<Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/jobPost">job Post</Nav.Link>
<NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id={`offcanvasNavbarDropdown-expand-${expand}`}>
<NavDropdown.Item href="#action3">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
... ... ...
<NavDropdown.Divider />
```

In App.js

```
<Route exact path="/">
      <Home></Home>
</Route>

<Route path="/home">
        <Home></Home>
</Route>

<Route path="/jobPost">
        <JobPost></JobPost>
</Route>
```

Need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

add this line,hope it will work

Comment: Added now  ```import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';``` but  same result. It works only after reloading.

Comment: use react-router-dom@v6, it works well in my project

Comment: It's still not working yet[Installed react-router-dom@v6].

Comment: OP is using RRDv5, so the fact you are using v6 and works differently is completely irrelevant.

Comment: It works:: in App.js ```<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/jobPost" element={<JobPost />} />``` and in Navbar.js ``` <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/jobPost">Post Job</Nav.Link>``` Thanks all.